# What is the best way to serve large javascript file libraries from a server with a slow upstream?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn, offline, iot

I want to put a webserver on my raspberry pi, but its upload speed is slow and I have a webpage with a big script (angular.js).

I could use a CDN for angular.js, but my ISP is not perfect, and I want to be able to serve the file even when the outside Internet is unavailable.

What is the best way to make the browser use one script when my network is connected to the rest of the Internet, but use another when the outside Internet is unavailable?

Comment: Your title suggests something different from your actual question.

Comment: You might want to consider using something a tad bit more powerful than a raspberry pi to host web pages from

Comment: I think you would need some method of pinging an external address to confirm if it can reach it. If the question was just "use different js based on whether browser is online or offline", that can be determined using `navigator.onLine`. but to know if the browser can reach the external web when the browser is online locally, you would need to check if a remote address is reachable.

Answer (score 1):

Save the contents of the file in Local Storage then use Javascript to insert the code for the file on to the web page.

Either that or use  cache-control headers.